# Scroll is moving too far

Tags: javascript, jquery, slimscroll

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uprwoa2s/).

Suppose the first visible element inside the scroll container is `#1` element. In the above fiddle, I can see `#1`, `#2`, `#3` and `#4` elements. and if I am right, if I scroll once I should be able to see next 4 elements i.e `#5`, `#6`, `#7` and `#8`. But when I scroll once through mousewheel, the scroll container is moving to `#15` element.

Please help.

```
// update content every second
function addChild() {
    var el = $('<div></div>').html('#' + $('#testDiv').children().length)
        .css({
        padding: '3px',
        border: '1px solid #ccc',
        margin: '5px'
    });
    $('#testDiv').append(el);

    // update slimscroll every time content changes
    $('#testDiv').slimscroll();
}

$('#testDiv').slimscroll({
    alwaysVisible: true,
    height: 150
});

for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    addChild();
}
```

PS: I filled an issue on [github](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/issues/213)

Comment: Er.. Works fine for me.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I am on chrome. jumps to me to `#15` element.

Comment: Setting attribute 'wheelStep:5' inside the slimscroll should solve this problem. '

Comment: @WisdmLabs is correct i think i tried by  **wheelStep:5** and worked fine

Comment: @WisdmLabs thanks that works. but I can't say that the content is always large in  it. For example, if there are only 30 items in the container, the scroll becoming slow.

Comment: Sorry for the constant changes , i had the height expanded to 200. It works properly for wheelStep : 5.

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
// update content every second
function addChild() {
    var el = $('<div></div>').html('#' + $('#testDiv').children().length)
        .css({
        padding: '3px',
        border: '1px solid #ccc',
        margin: '5px'
    });
    $('#testDiv').append(el);

    // update slimscroll every time content changes
    $('#testDiv').slimscroll();
}


for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    addChild();
}

$('#testDiv').slimscroll({
    alwaysVisible: true,
    height: 150
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uprwoa2s/5/)

I have just loaded the div before the `slimscroll`

Comment: Thanks, you made me realize that the content in my project is coming through ajax url which is async and the code is in deep forest. I think there is no other way than finding that ajax call back function where I need to add this slimscroll function.